# Filtering View by IP Address isn't excluding traffic

Tags: google-analytics

I've set up a filter on my View to exclude views of my website from my phone, more than 24 hours ago, like this -

*IP address removed*

[image: Filter criteria]

I've double checked that the IP address is an exact match, based on the address that Google shows me -

[image: Google IP address check]

but my new activity is still being shown in the View. Is there anything else I might be missing here?

Comment: Filters only apply to new data.  Are you trying to verify the filter is working by looking at data that had already been collected?

Comment: Good point but no, I'm checking it with new data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the GA tracking configured to anonymize IP data?
If so, then IP filtering will not work as expected, as anonymizing IPs masks the last octet of the IP address.

In these instances you have a few options:

1. Adjust the filter match to *that begin with* and leave the last octet in the IP address blank.    Keep in mind, this may have the unintended result of also filtering out other legit traffic, due to the IP range being caught by the filter being broader than intended.
2. Use an addon such as Ghostery to block GA tracking
3. Create a custom dimension with a User scope. On a private page on the site (non indexed and not linked to via other pages), add the tracking and configure it to send an event and the custom dimension named *block* with a value such as *myvisits* on page load.
   Create a View level custom exclude filter, to exclude the custom dimension *block* with the value *myvisits*.
   Bookmark the page and revisit it any time you clear your cookies/cache to reset  the custom dimension for your visits.

When filtering custom dimensions the filter must be created within the View at the View level. It cannot be created at the Account level and then applied to a View.
You will need to do this for each View where you want to exclude your visits.

If the IP address is an IPv6 address (eg will look similar to 2620:0:10e2:2:c4bc:9fd2:974f:cf19). Then use match type *that begin with* and shorten from the end of the IP address if necessary.

To check if IP data is being anonymized, you can use GA Debugger with Chrome Dev Tools, and it will show you what parameters and values are being sent with each hit to GA. aip parameter value will be 1 if IP anonymization is set to true/turned on.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure how to check whether the tracking's configured to anonymise the data but Google's [documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2763052?hl=en) mentions that it may be to comply with local data protection authorities and I'm in the UK so I wouldn't be surprised if it was. In my case my IP address was a string of 30 characters, separated by colons. I had to delete 19 characters from the end of the address in order to make the filter work, once I changed it to 'that begin with'. But it looks like that's done the job.

Comment: That's an IPv6 IP address then rather than an IPv4 address. In which case, yes the begins with match type should be used instead.